# How can I get my curl statement to correctly read google image guesses?

Tags: php, curl, preg-match

I am creating a little code that reads Google's best guess for images on their image search.

Click on the link so you can see what I am talking about.
http://images.google.com/searchbyimage?image_url=http://static.filestube.com/files/images/logo3.gif

If you click the link you can see that the results say: Best guess for this image: filestube logo

I want to be able to pull the best guess and return it

HERe IS MY CODE ThAT DOESNT WORK

```
$ch = curl_init("http://images.google.com/searchbyimage?image_url=http://static.filestube.com/files/images/logo3.gif");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
preg_match("Best guess for this image:&nbsp;(.*)</a>", $result, $matches);
if(empty($matches)){
    echo("No guess on this image. <br />");
} else{
    echo("Best guess for this image:");
    print_r($matches);
}
```

I keeps on returning no guess

Comment: You are not allowed to scrape Google search results, and they actively try and stop people. Even if you get it working, it won't work for long.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to try [Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview)?

Answer (score 0):

Well, when I run your code it says:

`Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash`

Correct your `preg_match` line with this:

```
preg_match("~Best guess for this image:&nbsp;(.*)</a>~", $result, $matches);
```

Your code it's ok at this point and it will run without errors but when executing it, you will see again this: `No guess on this image` because you now have a major problem. Take a look and if you `echo` your `$result` variable, you will always get this:

```
302 Moved
The document has moved here.
```

And not the page with the results like when going directly to the link you put.

So, you will never get a positive result. I assume it's a kind of protection from Google.

Try something new :-)

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into finding another way to search Google Images

Answer (score 0):

2 things that happened when testing your code:

first your regex is wrong. You need to escape characters, something like this:

```
preg_match("/Best guess for this image:&nbsp;(.*)<\/a>/", $result, $matches);
```

second, when printing $result I get a "302: document was moved" message, with a link poiting to

```
http://images.google.com/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZitt90SDPhLD9YMKK0zsGPwPtv7We9Nx0VHAncZh0XuZKPl_1Hqv8XGny1cs4jPSR-Byfk7P_1tBQp3Lu8p83b6yYDw_1g0v9ciHDp_1qZpBxV2lCsHVbk5MTlJYW4JdJqc683K4kk9D7k-AnmqI5fGS09xLBo0q57yYJVfgC1YPhn0u3gFW3loZIXQL30pJhulG7O5XdR-whIhu_1YQKWHGzrMEMP-rUrfoNWN0ndIv9_1vfckTr2hD0ziGMEG1Dc9kQ8XPZzdvDg0YmeyyxJhtaYK5Rgdbr9qBU4KG4GYkNPkcdPn1kq_1dRAhWNYob8aOsDK-596CLI5ys32TmsPL2riU6Hm7ov9rn_1r9ZpSDh5UmAMB72Sq2ERx6KsVMA25heuBeRlOUHTvmhgQXVL5uuqhoeqDNz0cFhHFwba3affnHn2A05apHXY2Wnf1KevEA-nYQ4TgFdBWw1XsY--kC3w03e6F_1TdxWIMLspObeLliPKOXlv7-iDg0NTcmrcKgtHknhTOMK6IsrGVhTMJnqNlorccmxyvlMCUNHslPTB9YXkusNlIs9_1H-CA1Tj79R8JWDU65ckTb9fOZ5zCkoQtouP-UkE5pLOEffXX7huJeMVF68s7vsLBGKc7-Jfm2jFoId9lnzmNjLv9NAm_1ifaVYx2rGiIhl9wcFjn3MerwS6BfjcBvHNxetxpey5vbX1gS0R4sUuV28hNdkYQbG54WmAYpqh5buBbSKHUMvFvKIUtrWIiY3PHqutuZzDJhriU6H8slX6yMhGm2c72BGG4KOZbRNg3E1oHWXHVSoLfG9zNybcW0Mf65aE4xFFq6g6dcckF5DBAYUp
```

The interesting thing is that if I run this code (curl the link "here")

```
preg_match('/(?<=(<A HREF="))(.*)(?=(\"\>here\<\/A\>))/', $result, $matches);

$ch = curl_init($matches[0]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

print $result;
```

I get the same page with a different URL so I'm guessing that google has some sort of protection to prevent piggyback.